# socket.io How to distinguish for which room is the message

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I send a message from the server to the two rooms.

```
io.to('room_one').emit('message', 'room_one');
io.to('room_two').emit('message', 'room_two');
```

When I use this client code, I get both messages.

```
socket.on('message', function (data) {      
    console.log(data);
});
```

But I want to distinguish for which room is the message.
I imagine that something like this can be done.

```
socket.on('room_one#message', function (data) {     
    console.log(data);
});

socket.on('room_two#message', function (data) {     
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the message arrives in the client, there is no internal indication of what room the message was sent to.  This is because a message isn't really sent to a room, but it's sent to connections that are in a room.

As such, when you receive the message there are just three ways that you could modify your code:

1. You could use a different message name.  You would have to `.emit()` a different message name on the server and you would have to listen for each  different message name in the client.
2. You could add a piece of data to the message (a property on an object sent as the data with the message) to indicate what room it was associated with.
3. You could use different connections for each room so a given connection was only in one room and thus you would know that any message sent to it was associated with that room.

---

Depending upon how similar or different the messages are, I'd probably select option 1 or option 2.  If the messages really are identical, just associated with a different room, I'd pick option 2.  If the messages actually have a different meaning in the different rooms, then I'd pick option 1.